# What is wrong with the phase control of my sine wave code?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, sign

I have created a sine wave drawing web app. Here is my code:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
  amplitude_slider = document.getElementById("amplitude_control"),
  wavelength_slider = document.getElementById("wavelength_control"),
  phase_slider = document.getElementById("phase_control"),
  amplitude_output = document.getElementById("amplitude_value"),
  wavelength_output = document.getElementById("wavelength_value"),
  phase_output = document.getElementById("phase_value"),
  radian_factor = Math.PI / 180;

var width,
  height,
  canvas_middle,
  context,
  amplitude = 20,
  wavelength = 0,
  phase = 0;

function init() {
  width = window.innerWidth - 4; //exclude 4 pixels for the border
  height = window.innerHeight - 4;
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height / 2;
  canvas_middle = height / 4;
  context = canvas.getContext("2d");
}

function draw() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  context.beginPath();
  var ampl = amplitude / 100 * canvas_middle;
  context.moveTo(0, canvas_middle + ampl * Math.sin(radian_factor * phase * Math.pow(2, wavelength)));
  for (i = 1; i < width; i++) {
    context.lineTo(i, canvas_middle + ampl * Math.sin(radian_factor * (i + phase) * Math.pow(2, wavelength)));
  }
  context.stroke();
}
init();
draw();
window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
  init();
  draw();
});

amplitude_slider.addEventListener("input", () => {
  amplitude = amplitude_slider.value;
  amplitude_output.innerHTML = amplitude;
  draw();
});
wavelength_slider.addEventListener("input", () => {
  wavelength = wavelength_slider.value;
  wavelength_output.innerHTML = Math.pow(2, wavelength).toFixed(2);
  draw();
});
phase_slider.addEventListener("input", () => {
  phase = phase_slider.value;
  phase_output.innerHTML = phase + "&deg; (" + (radian_factor * phase).toFixed(3) + "rad)";
  draw();
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

canvas {
  border: 2px solid green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 2em;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<input type="range" id="amplitude_control" value="20" min="0" max="100" step="0.1"> Amplitude <span id="amplitude_value">20</span><br>
<input type="range" id="wavelength_control" value="0" min="-5" max="5" step="0.01"> Wavelength <span id="wavelength_value">4.00</span><br>
<input type="range" id="phase_control" value="0" min="0" max="360" step="0.1"> Phase <span id="phase_value">0&deg; (0.000 rad)</span>
```

The **Amplitude** control and **Wavelength** control works fine, but the **Phase** control. I want it to be like this:
[image]
Phase 180 degree
[image]
Phase 90 degree

But, it is behaving very weirdly, you can see it for yourself by using the **Phase** slider. What mistake have I done?

Comment: I very nearly downvoted and VTC as a duplicate here. Please be careful of your question titles. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more info. *The title is the first thing potential answerers will see, and if your title isn't interesting, they won't read the rest. So make it count:*

Comment: It's the input value being a string tricking here. You need `phase = +phase_slider.value;`, i.e. convert the phase to a number before doing the math (`i + phase`).

Comment: Oh yes, you are right, I just needed to change the `phase_slider.value` to a number and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Please post this as an answer so that it helps others too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of *Temmu's* comment, I was able to solve my problem. In my code, the problem was that the **phase_slider.value** was returning a value of `string` type. Using that `string` type value for calculations was causing the problem.

I just needed to convert the **phase_slider.value** to a number by using `parseInt()` method or by putting a `+` sign before the variable.

Here is the corrected version of my code:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
  amplitude_slider = document.getElementById("amplitude_control"),
  wavelength_slider = document.getElementById("wavelength_control"),
  phase_slider = document.getElementById("phase_control"),
  amplitude_output = document.getElementById("amplitude_value"),
  wavelength_output = document.getElementById("wavelength_value"),
  phase_output = document.getElementById("phase_value"),
  radian_factor = Math.PI / 180;

var width,
  height,
  canvas_middle,
  context,
  amplitude = 20,
  wavelength = 0,
  phase = 0;

function init() {
  width = window.innerWidth - 4; //exclude 4 pixels for the border
  height = window.innerHeight - 4;
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height / 2;
  canvas_middle = height / 4;
  context = canvas.getContext("2d");
}

function draw() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  context.beginPath();
  var ampl = amplitude / 100 * canvas_middle;
  context.moveTo(0, canvas_middle + ampl * Math.sin(radian_factor * phase * Math.pow(2, wavelength)));
  for (i = 1; i < width; i++) {
    context.lineTo(i, canvas_middle + ampl * Math.sin(radian_factor * (i + phase) * Math.pow(2, wavelength)));
  }
  context.stroke();
}
init();
draw();
window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
  init();
  draw();
});

amplitude_slider.addEventListener("input", () => {
  amplitude = amplitude_slider.value;
  amplitude_output.innerHTML = amplitude;
  draw();
});
wavelength_slider.addEventListener("input", () => {
  wavelength = wavelength_slider.value;
  wavelength_output.innerHTML = Math.pow(2, wavelength).toFixed(2);
  draw();
});
phase_slider.addEventListener("input", () => {
  phase = parseInt(phase_slider.value); //This is the corrected line
  phase_output.innerHTML = phase + "&deg; (" + (radian_factor * phase).toFixed(3) + "rad)";
  draw();
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

canvas {
  border: 2px solid green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 2em;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<input type="range" id="amplitude_control" value="20" min="0" max="100" step="0.1"> Amplitude <span id="amplitude_value">20</span><br>
<input type="range" id="wavelength_control" value="0" min="-5" max="5" step="0.01"> Wavelength <span id="wavelength_value">4.00</span><br>
<input type="range" id="phase_control" value="0" min="0" max="360" step="0.1"> Phase <span id="phase_value">0&deg; (0.000 rad)</span>
```